# Partition and preserve data

Tags: partitioning, ntfs, external-hdd, format

I use Ubuntu 12.04 and have an external HD of 4 tera formated in FAT. There is a lot of data in this HD, much more than the note and take. I would like to create NTFS partitions in the external HD preserving all data stored there.

Does anyone know if/how that is possible? I'm new at Linux...

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can be able to create ntfs partitions on your external HDD.Just shrink the size of FAT filesystem and then create NTFS partitions from the free or unallocated space.

It would preserve the data inside your HDD.

Answer (score 0):

You can create new partitions, but if your intent is to convert from FAT to NTFS, I'm not aware of any tools that can do that. Also, NTFS is a poor choice of filesystem for use in Ubuntu (or any other Linux distribution); for Linux use, you should be using a Linux-native filesystem such as ext3fs, ext4fs, or XFS. NTFS is a tolerable choice for dual-boot scenarios, but it's got serious problems even then. Personally, I'd stick with FAT for a dual-boot Linux/Windows setup unless FAT's file-size limits became an issue.

Comment: many thanks! this is useful. the file-size IS the issue. I'll take a chance with the linux native options.